# Moved mySQL DB with success but page Ids wont call and issues with user registration/approval

Tags: php, html, mysql

So we have a website running a online system that is completely functional and have been for several years now. We are applying the same ideology to our other website and copying the same system to a new domain. My friend gave me the entire structure. I already moved everything and he gave me a clean DB which was moved with success using the following:

```
mysqldump -u root -p dbname > public_location/db.sql
```

I created the database on the new server, created the user, then:

```
mysqldump -u root -p dbname < db.sql
```

Almost everything is working. The structure is also precisely equal but we have user registration forms which for some reason users get no notifications of sign up and also in the main menu, the structure calling the page ids is not working with all the pages but giving our default error:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" border="0" width="949" align="center" class="box">
<tr><td id="Message" width="100%"><table width='100%'><tr><td class='Err' width='100%'>please select a valid information link</td></tr></table></td></tr>
<tr><td><p style="text-align:justify;"></p></td></tr>
</table>
```

I am assuming that since he provided me with a blank DB I need to set a load of variables that are missing, especially the SMTP ones to get my mailing system correct. Can anyone help me direct so I can get this system completely online and I also really want to learn so I have been reading to better learn how to handle these database moves because I have done it before but entire websites from one place to the other but not a hand built website with an empty database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check your error logs? Are you running the same versions of mysql? Can you explain more about `the structure calling the page ids is not working` and/or show the code related to it?

Comment: Hi! Yes, the SQL dump file says: -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10deb1  and in phpMyAdmin I have phpMyAdmin Version information: 4.3.8. As for the ids for instance in the code from the menu:
`<li><a href="./html/info_page.php?id=1">New Driver FAQ</a></li>` should load a page with a FAQ but it returns that error, but the link below that:
`<li><a href="./html/info_page.php?id=9">User Application Step-1</a></li>`
Is indeed able to pull up a registration form. Then again:                                          `<li><a href="./html/info_page.php?id=3">Driver Agreement</a></li>` is not.

Comment: Are records 1 and 3 in the database? How does the action of 1 and 3 differ from 9? You to debug the issue a but more. I think the versions you are reading are phpmyadmin, not mysql. If you are using MySQL 4 that might be your issue, that is +11 years old.

Comment: Sorry.. I just double checked.  id 9 is also not pulling up anything..  
`<!--<li><a href="info_page.php?id=1">New Driver FAQ</a></li>-->` pulls nothing
`<!--<li><a href="info_page.php?id=9">User Application Step-1</a></li>-->` pulls nothing
`<li><a href="adduser.php">User Registration <!--Step-2--></a></li>` pulls a complete form because it is indeed in the database through `tbl_user`. I doubled checked the versions and I am running MySQL 5.5.51 and he is running 5.5.49.

Comment: Same PHP versions, correct/same credentials? Nothing in the logs?

Comment: Last error was: `[23-Oct-2016 16:00:24] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Access denied for user 'usrname'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in ///public_html/html/connect02.php on line 3` which I fixed it.  PHP Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17

Comment: that error was in /public_html/error_log is there another log file?